# How do I cast my NSArray to List<UIView> in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Got back a list of views from a XIB and I need to reference them individually.

```
var headerViews = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("LoginUpdateHeader",this,null);
```

I can't seem to do this as I get an error about not being able to apply indexing with [] to type Foundation.NSArray:

```
var view1 = headerViews[0];
```

So I figure I need to convert the NSArray to something like a list. How do I do this or how do I reference the different elements of the NSArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
var view1 = headerViews.GetItem<UIView> (0);
```

**Long answer**

An `NSArray` can contains different types of elements - and even non `NSObject` subclasses (e.g. `CF*` types). That makes using an indexer not very practical, since it will always end up being casted (because nothing else than `NSObject` can be used).

Whenever possible (if all the types are identical) Xamarin's bindings are done using the element type, e.g. `NSString[] GetList ()`.